# Android virtual device not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I create a virtual device it dosnt work. There is no green signal next to the device, and when i start it it opens but does not work properly. Anyone have an idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I go to the virtual device manager and press on "Device definition"I press on "creat AVD" and the virtual device is listed on my android virtual devices, although like I said, it dos, then press on Nexus 4. I dont have a green signal next to it, but a blue one the shape of a hand watch. Then I press on "start" to start the device. the virtual device opens, on top it says: 5554 AVD_for_nexus_4_by_google. The problem is the device dosnt work properly. It dosnt have the Nexus 'home' and 'back' buttons. There is a caption that says "swipe to get started" but the virtual evice simply does not work.

Comment: You should mention all this in the question itself. Otherwise it appears off-topic according to SO rules

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue.
First : It takes some time to start-up a virtual device. Wait for the device to boot properly. This can take up to 5 minutes, depending on the device you are choosing.
Second: Play with the device parameters: memory, start from disk, ... This can improve startup time.